# Why is my WiFi slow when I send a video using broadcast UDP packets on a different network (albeit sharing the same NIC)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, speed

I have a setup where I send UDP broadcast packet for a video app.

I run a VPS on my server and send UDP packets to a Jetson computer. The two are on the `10.0.2.x` network. They both use my second server NIC. On that NIC I also have a WiFi router, but that one is on network `192.168.2.x`.

Why would sending broadcast UDP packets slow down the WiFi when I use a mere 1/5th of the available bandwidth and the WiFi use about 1/3rd? (and the rest is used by another computer).

Here is a basic representation of the network:

```
             +--------------+
             | Server       |
             |  +-------+   |
             |  | NIC 1 |   |    +---------+     +----------+
Internet <----->|       |   |    | Switch  |     | Jetson   |
             |  +-------+   |    | 1Gbit   |<--->|          |
             |      ^       |    |         |     +----------+
             |      |       |    |         |
             |      v       |    |         |
             |  +-------+   |    |         |     +----------+      +-----------------+
             |  | NIC 2 |   |    |         |     | WiFi     |      | WiFi Computer   |
             |  |       |<------>|         |<--->|          |\/\/\/|                 |
             |  +-------+   |    |         |     +----------+   ^  +-----------------+
             |        ^     |    |         |                    |
             |        |     |    |         |                    \______ slow WiFi connection
             |        v     |    |         |     +----------+
             |   +--------+ |    |         |     | Other    |
             |   | VPS    | |    |         |<--->| Computer |
             |   |        | |    +---------+     +----------+
             |   +--------+ |                           ^_______ speed not affected
             |              |
             +--------------+
```

So computers connected to the Switch using a network cable work fine. Those connected over the WiFi get impeded, as if the WiFi router was trying to forward the packets for `10.0.2.x` when the router itself is a `192.168.2.x` address.

Just in case, for those who did not grasp the network yet, I'm **not** trying to broadcast over WiFi. I'd actually would like the WiFi router to be totally ignored in that case. I know broadcasting through WiFi is a big "no! no!".

Just in case, here is the menu of the router. It's a Belkin.

[image]

Comment: Does your WiFi router show its CPU usage statistics anywhere?

Comment: @user1686 I added the router menu. I've not seen a way to do that. There is no telnet/ssh connection either. I guess I have a rather old WiFi router, too...

Comment: It's not necessarily about it being _old_ -- I do suspect that handling all the broadcasts does overload its CPU (1/5th of 1 Gbps is quite a bit of packets), but it might be because of some "intrusion detection" feature rather than the CPU alone, _or_ it might have a weak CPU because it was designed to offload normal traffic to a dedicated packet-forwarding core, but broadcasts end up bypassing that offload and hammering the CPU anyway. This would be my 1st guess.

Comment: But that said, do you actually _receive_ these broadcasts over Wi-Fi on your computer (as shown by tcpdump/Wireshark), or does the router just become slow without sending anything on air?

Comment: What is keeping the broadcasts off the WiFi network? Are you using VLANs? Or do you have multiple logical networks on the same physical network? I suspect a high level of network broadcasts on the router's interface is overloading it -- it has to receive and inspect each broadcast packet, likely requiring interrupts, context switches, and other things it can't handle at that rate. What WiFi device?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think Spiff nailed it. It gets forwarded to the WiFi router because it's connected to the same switch. Pretty much what user1686 was saying too. I have multiple IPs on the same NIC, so one physical network but multiple LAN (192.168.2.x and 10.0.2.x travels on the same switch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this it's useful to think of Wi-Fi as wireless Ethernet. It sounds like your Belkin Wi-Fi "router" isn't *routing* between wired and wireless, it's just bridging. So it's just acting as a plain AP.

Ethernet (wired or wireless) doesn't know anything about IP. So your AP is just being an Ethernet bridge. That is, it's following the 802.1D rules for bridges and switches, and only paying attention to Ethernet-layer (MAC) addresses, and using the destination Ethernet addresses to decide what to bridge across to wireless, and what to drop.

I'm guessing you're sending your UDP broadcasts to your subnet-broadcast IP address of 10.0.2.255. So per the standards, those IP packets will be inside Ethernet frames addressed to Ethernet multicast MAC address 01:00:5e:00:02:ff (even if I got the conversion wrong, it's still an Ethernet multicast MAC address).

So your AP sees a multicast destination MAC address, and, following standard 802.1D rules for bridges and switches, it automatically bridges it across to Wi-Fi and sends it as a Wi-Fi multicast.

Unfortunately, multicasts and broadcasts are VERY expensive on Wi-Fi, in terms of airtime usage.

Wi-Fi multicasts must be sent at a kind of "lowest common denominator" signaling rate to ensure that all wireless clients will be able to receive them successfully. This is often just the lowest possible signaling rate for that band. So that's 1Mbps for 2.4GHz, and 6Mbps for 5GHz.

So for example a 1Mbps broadcast or multicast video stream will try to use **ALL** of the airtime on the 2.4GHz channel, and 1/6th of the airtime on the 5GHz channel. And this is UDP, not TCP, so there's no congestion control algorithm in place, so it won't share bandwidth well with others.

One solution might be to enable IGMP Snooping in your AP, if it supports it. I'm not sure off the top of my head, but you might also need to switch to UDP multicasts instead of broadcasts in order for IGMP to get involved so that IGMP Snooping can work.

Another solution might be to use VLANs to actually separate your two IP subnets into two separate Ethernet-layer networks.

One more solution would be to enable routing (IP forwarding) or NAT on your Belkin Wi-Fi device, so separate your wireless LAN from your wired LAN. You'd need to do it carefully or you could break some kinds of connectivity / discoverability between the wireless LAN and the wired LAN.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know as much about the low level implementation of network, but this way it makes sense. So the best for me to have another port...